# How can I speed up queries with `GROUP BY` in them?

Tags: indexing, group-by, mariadb

## Details:

- MariaDB: Server version: 10.2.10-MariaDB MariaDB Server
- The DB table, `trans_tbl` is using Aria DB engine
- Table is somewhat large: 126,006,123 rows
- Server is not at all large: AWS t3 micro w/attached 30GB EBS

I applied indexes to this DB table as follows:

- A primary key: `evt_id`
- Another index on the column I want to group by: `transaction_type`

## 3 Related Questions:

1. Why is the `transaction_type` index ignored when I perform the following?

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(evt_id), transaction_type FROM trans_tbl GROUP BY transaction_type
   ```

   If I look at the output from `EXPLAIN`, I see:

   ```
   MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(evt_id), transaction_type FROM trans_tbl GROUP BY transaction_type;
   +------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------+
   | id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                           |
   +------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------+
   |    1 | SIMPLE      | trans_tbl | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 126006123 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
   +------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------+
   ```

   What's confusing me here is that **both** of the items in the query are indexed. So, shouldn't the index(es) be utilized?
2. Why **is** the `transaction_type` index being used in the following case, where all I've done is switched from `COUNT(evt_id)` -- the primary key -- to `COUNT(1)`. (The column is `transaction_type`, the index generated from it is called `TransType`.)

   ```
   MariaDB [my_db]> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1), transaction_type FROM trans_tbl GROUP BY transaction_type;
   +------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
   | id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra       |
   +------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
   |    1 | SIMPLE      | trans_tbl | index | NULL          | TransType | 35      | NULL | 126006123 | Using index |
   +------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
   ```
3. The first query (with `COUNT(evt_id)`) takes 2 minutes & 40 seconds. Since it is not using the indices, that makes sense.  But the second query (with `COUNT(1)`) takes 50 seconds. This makes no sense to me. Shouldn't it take essentially 0 seconds? Can't it just look at the first and last index value of each group, subtract them, and have the count? It seems to me that it is indeed actually counting. What's the point of an index?

   - I guess my more important question is: **How do I set up my indexes to allow for grouping on that index to return results almost instantaneously, as I would expect?**

PS I know the machine is ridiculously underpowered for this size of DB table. But, the table data is not worth throwing a lot of money at it to improve performance. I'd rather just learn to implement Aria indexes properly to gain speed.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I **have** forced the use of the index on the first query, and it actually slowed down that first query's execution time.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT(*)`? `COUNT(field)` requires inspecting the field values as COUNT only counts non-null values. (You'd think it might be able to take advantage of the field you're referencing being NOT NULLable, but there are only so many optimizations they can do in the face of so many use cases, a LEFT JOIN would make such an optimization moot anyway). Also, MySQL generally only takes advantage of one index at a time, so having both field indexed separately is of little help; a compound index on (transaction_type, evt_id) _might_ help though.

Comment: My upvote to counterbalance the downvote. Your question is legitimate and well written.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin Yeah, I'm not sure why I got the downvote, but I try not to sweat the little stuff...

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL` before counting the row.

`COUNT(*)` is the usual pattern for counting rows.

So...

```
SELECT COUNT(evt_id), transaction_t is just `SELECT FIND_IN_SET(17, '8,12,17,90');`ype
    FROM trans_tbl GROUP BY transaction_type;
```

decided to do a table scan, then sort and group.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), transaction_type
    FROM trans_tbl GROUP BY transaction_type;
```

saw `INDEX(transaction_type)` and said "goodie; I can just scan that index without having to sort."  Note:  It still has to scan in order to count.  But the `INDEX` is smaller than the table, so it could be done faster.  This is also called a "covering" index since all the columns needed in the `SELECT` are found in that one `INDEX`.

`COUNT(1)` *might* be treated the same as `COUNT(*)`, I don't know.

<strike>`INDEX(transaction_type)` is essentially identical to `INDEX(transaction_type, evt_id)`.  This because the `PRIMARY KEY` is silently tacked onto any secondary key in InnoDB.</strike>

I don't know why `INDEX(transaction_type, evt_id)` was not used.  Bottom line:  Use `COUNT(*)`.

Why not 0 seconds?  The counts are not saved anywhere.  Anyway, there could be other queries modifying the counts as you run you `SELECT`.  The improvement came from scanning 126M 2-column rows instead of 126M multi-column rows.

Comment: "INDEX(transaction_type) is essentially identical to INDEX(transaction_type, evt_id)" - It's AriaDB - not InnoDB.

Comment: Hi @Rick Thanks! Yeah, I knew I could do `count(*)` (or `count(1)`, as I show here). I was just trying to understand.  The concern with `NULL` values makes sense, but I'm still perplexed: why a table scan?  I have set up an index? Shouldn't the index also sort `NULL` values? E.g., putting all the `NULL` at the bottom or top of the index?? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson - The `INDEX` will have all the `NULLs` first.  To discover whether it is doing a full index scan versus a range scan (`IS NOT NULL`), use `Handler%` values as discussed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) .  I'll be interested to hear what you discover for _your_ case.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson - Caveat:  I do know if what I say applies to Aria tables.